# Combine multiple rows with N-1 identical columns and 1 different column into one row, preserving the first N-1 columns and summing the last column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that produces a table with 26 columns, A-Z. For some rows, columns A-Y are identical, and column Z is the only one that differs. Is there an easy and clean way to combine duplicate rows, such that columns A-Y are the same and column Z is summed over? My solution is to do something like

```
SELECT A, B, C,...,Y,SUM(Z)
-- lots of work
FROM [table produced by multiple joins]
GROUP BY A, B, C,...,Y
```

The last `GROUP BY` clause ends up being *very* long. It's also prone to making mistakes if columns are ever added or removed from the `SELECT` statement. Is this the only way to go about what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ANY_VALUE((SELECT AS STRUCT t.* EXCEPT(z))).*,
  SUM(z) AS z
FROM `project.dataset.table_produced_by_multiple_joins` t
GROUP BY FORMAT('%t', (SELECT AS STRUCT t.* EXCEPT(z)))
```

Comment: Congratulations on the 100k!

Comment: Thank you, @GMB :o)